# is there a way to get this sort of reflection on an object?

Tags: reflection

i found this vaporwave image and i would like to know if you can get a sort of rainbow reflection like this? basically i want to make a holographic reflection

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also try this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMiXPjwSkEo

Comment: how can i get the "dot product" node

Comment: nevermind i found it